# Replace matrix entries in Matlab based on their value and their index

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, I want to replace those entries in a matrix that their values equal to their row index with one, and the others with zero.

For example

```
A = [3 1 4
     2 2 5
     1 3 3];
```

and I want to have

```
B = [0 1 0
     1 1 0 
     0 1 1];
```

Is there any way to do so efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit more generic:

MATLAB before R2016b:

```
B = bsxfun(@eq, A, (1:size(A,1)).');
```

MATLAB R2016b and later:

```
B = ( A == (1:size(A,1)).' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
k = size (A) ;
for i = 1 : k(1)
    for j = 1 : k(2)
        if (A(i,j) == i )
            A(i,j) = 1;
        else
            A(i,j) = 0 ;
        end
    end
end
```

Alternative as per stewie suggestion:

```
bsxfun (@eq, A, [1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3])
```

Comment: @StewieGriffin: It was my mistake that I did not read his question properly. However, I added some code based on your suggestion in my answer. Thanks